# CARS microscopy

Tags: microscopy, raman-spectroscopy

I have probably very naive question.

In case of CARS microscopy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_anti-Stokes_Raman_spectroscopy we have $ω_{pr}+ω_{p}-ω_{S}$, how can we have minus $ω_S$? 
In fluorescent microscopy we always add energy after hitting/absorption.
I can think that, from mechanical point of view, in case of three photons ($pr$, $p$, and $S$), $S$ should hit the electron (atom) in opposite direction in order to decrease kinetic energy; is it right? It is interesting to see why we have minus?

Answer (score 0):

Think of $(\omega_{p} - \omega_s)$ as one term. It is the difference between the pump and stokes beam.

So $\omega_{pr} + \omega_{p} - \omega_s$ becomes $\omega_{pr}+(\omega_{p} - \omega_s)$ which is the probe beam frequency $\omega_{pr}$ plus the difference between the pump and stokes $(\omega_{p} - \omega_s)$

Comment: If we look from elector-magnetic point of view, how can we subtract 2 frequencies? Is it possible only if we have waves propagating in opposite directions?

Comment: I think it is better to think in terms of energies rather than frequencies. 

So completely ignore the frequencies and instead imagine them as the energy corresponding to that frequency. 

So you can add energies and subtract them, and each energy has a corresponding frequency. 

$e=\hbar \omega$

Comment: You can do the same thing with acoustics: mixing two wavelengths produces both $\omega_1 + \omega_2$ and $\omega_1 - \omega_2$ . It's a natural outcome of summing sin waves.